# Formatting CSV file of historical stock data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a csv file of historical stock data that I would like to format accordingly to import into another application.

The issues I'm having are particular with the date, there's a comma in the middle so I can't get the text to columns to work properly as it splits the date. Then when I remove the date column with fixed width and try to apply formulas to that it doesn't do anything and I set the data type to date. No idea what's going on there.

The next issue is after splitting the remaining 6 columns it's dropping off trailing zeroes. In text to columns I'm leaving it as general as that's supposed to convert numeric to numbers but it seems to be converting to text.

**I would like it eventually be like this,**

**dd-mm-yy, number, number, number, number, number**

28-Mar-17,226029.00,230971.00,226029.00,230549.00,968821

Any suggestions would be really helpful

Here is the data received as it comes from the site, opened downloaded csv file in a text editor and pasted here as is.

"Date","Price","Open","High","Low","Vol.","Change %"

"Sep 05, 2017","49,530","49,663","49,680","49,456","0","-0.17"

"Sep 04, 2017","49,614","49,603","49,808","49,445","12.49K","-0.44"

"Sep 01, 2017","49,831","49,900","50,016","49,751","21.00K","0.00"

"Aug 31, 2017","49,831","49,550","49,893","49,495","22.17K","0.72"

Comment: Don't split on `,` but on `","` and remove the remaining `"` in first and last column.

Comment: "splitting the remaining 4 columns" ... `"Date","Price","Open","High","Low","Vol.","Change %"` I count 6 remaining after Date

Comment: "In text to columns I'm leaving it as general as that's supposed to convert numeric to numbers but it seems to be converting to text." - I have no idea what you are trying to tell us, here. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: `dd-mm-yy` for March, 28th 2017 would be `28-03-17`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Fildor. I couldn't split with "," but used your idea and split with " instead. Left me with some extra columns which I could easily remove and keep what I needed. Also allowed me to get the date recognized as a date (which is what I needed, sorry about saying incorrect date format). Thanks I just needed another way of looking at it will close now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the option to save the csv file, and then import it into Excel?

Say you've saved as csv file as you've shown:

```
"Date","Price","Open","High","Low","Vol.","Change %"
"Sep 05, 2017","49,530","49,663","49,680","49,456","0","-0.17"
"Sep 04, 2017","49,614","49,603","49,808","49,445","12.49K","-0.44"
"Sep 01, 2017","49,831","49,900","50,016","49,751","21.00K","0.00"
"Aug 31, 2017","49,831","49,550","49,893","49,495","22.17K","0.72"
```

Then you can "Import External Data"...

[image: Import External Data Step 1]

...select comma as partition...

[image: Step 2]

...and you can tell Excel how to import the data:

[image: Step 3]

Comment: Thanks @lebelinoz for the screenshots. For your question yes I can indeed save the csv file and import into excel so didn't need an external data source. Went through the steps and it is sorted out now.

Comment: Excellent, I am happy to help. If you found this answer useful, please accept it by clicking the checkmark near the top of my answer